# open a new window on mouse click in React

Tags: reactjs, electron

I am creating a desktop application with electron. I want to open a new window with different dimension after the log in button is clicked. I am using Ipc renderer to pass message to the main.js file to resize the window object. But it does not seem to work.

```js
private handleonclick(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) {
  this.props.onLogin(this.state.user, this.state.password, this.state.domain, this.state.role);
  this.setState({
    loginSent: true,
    showWindow: false
  });
  const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');
  ipcRenderer.send('resize-me-please')
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

in Mains.js

```js
let { ipcMain } = require('electron') 
ipcMain.on('resize-me-please', function () {
  win.setSize(400,400 );
  return win;
});
```

Comment: what's `win` in the callback? what do u expect from returning it?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `BrowserWindow` from the `event` you receive using [`fromWebContents`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#browserwindowfromwebcontentswebcontents) static method.

Thus, to resize it in your callback you can write

```
ipcMain.on('resize-me-please', (event) => {
  BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(event.sender)
    .setSize(400, 400)
})
```